# How to get SSL certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, aruba

I purchased a domain with DNS management on Aruba and I pointed it to an ec2 instance using elastic IP.

Now the questions are:

-How can I get an SSL certificate for my website?
-Should I ask Aruba or AWS?
-And is it possible to get it for free?

If it can be useful, my website is written in nodejs.

Comment: Have you heard about [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)?

Comment: Yes i read about this, but is the certificate permanent? Because i read that i have to install it manually, and it isn't so convenient if I have to install it every month.

Comment: It lasts for 90 days, but it is possible to [configure it for auto-renewal](https://certbot.eff.org/about/). I know this is not the easiest solution in the world (which is why I haven't provided an answer), but it has the potential to save you some money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AWS world you can use AWS ACM (Amazon Certificate Manager). ACM provides free certificates with auto renewal, but it can be attached only to certain number of services like ELB, API Gateway, CloudFront... No way you can attach it to EC2, because ACM doesn’t provide private keys for you.

If you want to have only one EC2 with EIP, please, use Let’s Encrypt or buy certificate somewhere. Let’s Encrypt could be configured for auto renewal but, from my experience, it can broke suddenly.

AWS ACM works great

Comment: If I want to use AWS ACM I have to set an ELB and connect it to my ec2, is right? And do you know about the monthly cost of ELB?

Comment: Correct. About ELB pricing you need to check ELB pricing page. You need to use ALB for that. https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/pricing It's billing by hours and capacity units